Movie depicting aliens physically connected into group-mind
I think this was a made-for-TV movie, and I think I saw it in the late '80s or early '90s.

A small group of humans are fleeing on a spaceship from a bad guy,
also human, on another spaceship. 
The fleeing humans are led by a
smart young blond woman.  From the way she delivered her
lines, I got the impression that she might have been portrayed by a
Shakespearean actress. 
The fleeing humans take refuge on a planet
inhabited by humanoid aliens.  The aliens are ruled by a group mind,
which looks like a pulsating gelatinous mass (or possibly a painted
weather balloon) with individual aliens inside it. 
When questions are
posed to the group mind, one or more of the aliens' faces emerge from
the surface, intone a few words, and are then reabsorbed. 
I seem to
remember that the individual aliens that make up the group mind are
in constant agony.

It turns out the aliens have malevolent intentions, and the humans have to escape from them.  In an unforseen twist, the original pursuing bad guy arrives and ends up saving the day(!)  I'd appreciate any help in identifying this movie.

It reminds me of Battle Beyond the Stars...

I've seen Battle Beyond the Stars, and that's not it.  Thanks, though.

I looked through Wikipedia's List of Science Fiction Television Films, and I'm pretty sure the movie I'm looking for is The Warlord: Battle for the Galaxy.
